# How to change color for v-for elements with Firestore data

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, vue.js

My project is like Twitter.

What I can do:

- show posts
- show likes(numbers) in realtime

What I cannot do:

- show color changes in each like icon

Here are the code:

My Firestore database:

```
posts {
  content: string,
  likes: 0,
}
```

Vue:

```
<li v-for="post in posts" :key="post.id">
  <p>{{ post.content }}</p>
  <div>
    <v-icon @click="posts(post.id)">mdi-heart</v-icon>
    <span> {{ post.likes }} </span>
  </div>
</li>
```

JavaScript:

```
method: {
  like () {
    if (I didn't like) {
      // change the color of like icon of the post.
    } else {
      // change the color back.
    })
  }
}
```

**So... How Can I change the color for each post's like icon?**

(working on the newest versions of Vue.js, Vuetify, Nuxt.js, Firebase.)

Comment: It sounds like you might have to learn CSS to style your HTML elements.

Comment: Hi Doug, thanks for comment. I think CSS can't change "each" element in list. CSS changes every element.

Comment: You can style each element separately if you want.

Comment: I have no idea about that... Could you tell me more please?

Comment: Hint: use `v-bind.style` or `v-bind:class`. These use cases are covered by the documentation: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html

Comment: Thank you, Terry. I read the page, but seems I didn't understand... I will read it again.

Comment: Since you use Vuetify, you can dynamically assign a colour class from Vuetify https://vuetifyjs.com/en/styles/colors/ by following Terry’s advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<template>
  ...
  ...
  <div :class="bindLike">
    <v-icon @click="posts(post.id)">mdi-heart</v-icon>
    <span> {{ post.likes }} </span>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  computed: {
    bindLike: function() {
      return post.likes > 0 ? 'liked' : 'notliked';
    }
  },
}
</script>

<style>
.liked { background: blue; }
.notliked { background: transparent; }
</style>
```

this may work for you..!
But, ideal would be create a new component `PostLikes` and pass **mode, count** as props.